# Ruby syntax including "scan", "join", and "=="

Tags: ruby, join

Could someone breakdown each part of `k.scan(fish).join == query` in the following code and tell me what it does?

```
@entries = {"fish" => "aquatic animal", "fiend" => "wicked person"}

def find(fish)
    @entries.select { |k, v| k.scan(fish).join == query}
end
```

Comment: What is `query`? What values are you passing into the method `find`? Have you read the documentation for `scan` and `join`? Have you tried entering this into IRB to see what it returns for values as you try things? We need to know what you've tried and what you think is happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
k.scan(fish)
```

[String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) function search for matches to given argument, in this case `fish` and returns an array with all the matches it found.

```
k.scan(fish).join
```

The [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) connect array elements (which the scan function gave before) into one string.

Then  the result (a string) is being compared `==` to the `query` variable (don't know where the 'query' variable came from- It's not defined in your code.

If the string is equal to the query, then the hash pair (`{"fish" => "aquatic animal", "fiend" => "wicked person"}`) will be kept (that's what the select function does)